# EF4 Rollback Refresh don't refresh store values

Tags: entity-framework-4, rollback

i have this in EF4:

```
SomeClass ObjectX;

using (MyBDcontext ctx = ModelHelper.GetObjectContext())
  ObjectX = ctx.GetObjectByKey(Entity.EntityKey);

ObjectX.SomeProperty = StoreValue + 1;

using (MyBDcontext ctx = ModelHelper.GetObjectContext()){

//I get the same object
SomeClass AnotherObjectX = (SomeClass)ctx.GetObjectByKey(ObjectX.EntityKey);

//I do a DeepCopy(copyFrom, copyTo)
ModelHelper.DeepCopy(ObjectX, AnotherObjectX);

var objects = (from entry in ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                          EntityState.Modified)
                          where entry.EntityKey != null
                          select entry.Entity);

ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, objects);
}
```

My problem is that the object ObjectX after run Refresh() is with the same values, not the store values. why?

in var objects exist an instance of ObjectX and is refresh with the store values but my intance not change.

sorry about my english, thanks for the help...

Edit:

thank for the help Gert, i will try to explain my self:

//Store values

ObjectX.SomeProperty = 0

//Edit in memory

ObjectX.SomeProperty = 1

//For some reason i wanna cancel all change and return store values ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, objects);

//ObjectX.SomeProperty have the value = 1, it's supust to be 0 (store value)

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a similar scenario. Refresh with `StoreWins` replaces the value set before.

Comment: i edited my question, thanks

Comment: Now you add a pretty relevant detail. You create a new context and then immediately refresh its entries. Of course it's got no entries yet, `objects` is empty.

Comment: you are right. I thought that was my situation but there is a little important different. I gonna edit the question again. Now objects have a object, i refresh and the object in objects is refresh but not ObjectX. By the way i noob jajaja. I try ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ObjectX) but not work

Comment: Maybe use using(context blabla) is a bad practice and instead i have to create a context for all the cicle life of my aplication

Comment: `using` bad practice? You should get yourself some EF examples. They'll al tell you the opposite. You're going from bad to worse. You probably shouldn't even need to refresh entities at all. Also, why do you still use EF4?

Comment: yes, i gonna read more about EF. why do i still use EF4? i don't know. I have a lot of code working with .edmx with code Generation Strategies in Legacy objectContext, and when i try to change it to T4 i got a lot of errors. Also update EF to the last one version implies update aaaaalllll the clients computers with the last version of Frammework